# Are there particular requirements for cabling or conduit use for outdoor lights in the UK?

Tags: wiring, lighting, outdoor, 240v, uk

I'm seeing a lot of conflicting information about outdoor wiring, whether conduits, steel armour, etc. are necessary. I assume this might be due to particular 'zones' as in bathrooms, but I can't find any information on that - e.g. steel armour for cable on a wall, particularly above some height, seems pointless to me.

My question then is for outdoor *lighting* in particular, wall-mounted, coming through the wall (already, at about 1m high) from inside: do I need to use conduit, or any particular kind (or IPX4 (surely *all* cable is pretty much IP67+, the ends excluded, anyway..) or otherwise 'outdoor' rated) of cable?

I'm *not* asking about fixtures and junction boxes etc., purely cable.